# Trouble Getting z-index Working

Tags: z-index, css

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surfjam/bJU5c/2/) I made for an example. I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm missing. My intention is for the class of .tss-content to sit between #wrap-a and #tss on the z axis.

In other words, trying to get the white layer positioned between the grey and the blue layers.

I'm sure it's something dumb, but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

this is not possibile, since your `.tss-content` is nested inside an element `#tss` (gray) whose z-index is greater than `#wrap-a` (blue). So  `.tss-content` can't be shown between the two elements (with a middle z-index)

But If you want simply to visually overlap both the elements just remove `position: relative;` and `z-index: 99999;` from `.tss-social`

Comment: So if I move the divs with class .tss-content to where they're siblings of #tss, should that do it?

Comment: Ultimately I'm using this with some jQuery to slide .tss-content from behind #tss on mouseEnter/Leave events. I have all that working except for not being able to hide .tss-content behind #tss.

Answer (score 0):

You can float the white boxes and give a left value to push it to the right side

```
.tss-social {
    float:left;
    left: 50px;
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/bJU5c/4/)

Comment: I really need to get .tss-content hidden behind #tss so I can slide it out from behind on mouse events later. That part works, just that .tss-content is not hidden.

Comment: @MichaelDavis, It cannot be hidden, It is a child of #tss

Comment: @MichaelDavis, If you change your markup to something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/bJU5c/5/) i can help you out.